# Why does cp need -r while mv doesn't?

Tags: cp, mv

To copy a directory and its contents `cp` requires a `-r` switch.

To move a directory and its contents `mv` does not require a `-r` switch.

What is the reason for this?

EDIT: Don't worry. Despite searching, I found out after posting this question that it has been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46066/why-unix-mv-program-doesnt-need-r-recursive-option-for-directories-but-cp-do).

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `mv` command you're just changing metadata about the top level directory or individual file, when you're using the `cp` command you're literally making copies of a individual file or a directory tree. In order to differentiate between these two modes, the `cp` command needs you to specify which behavior you want to enlist.

You can view the metadata using `stat`.

```
$ stat /home/vagrant/adir
  File: ‘/home/vagrant/adir’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 794269      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-07-14 10:57:17.103849041 -0400
Modify: 2018-07-14 10:57:17.103849041 -0400
Change: 2018-07-14 10:57:17.103849041 -0400
 Birth: -
```

After we move it:

```
$ stat /tmp/adir
  File: ‘/tmp/adir’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 794269      Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-07-14 10:57:17.103849041 -0400
Modify: 2018-07-14 10:57:17.103849041 -0400
Change: 2018-07-14 10:57:53.323950044 -0400
 Birth: -
```

The `mv` command is just manipulating the metadata regarding the directory, and so doesn't need to actually make copies of anything to do this work.